# How do I make protobuf case-insensitive?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have a protobuf contract like this,

`message Car{
        string carId = 1;
    }`

I generate java classes from this contract and use it to parse JSON request.

Now if my JSON has "CarID" or "carid" then protobuf generated java classes don't recognize that field. How do I make it case-insensitive?

Comment: My understanding is that the protobuf JSON serializer is always case sensitive. So... don't use "CarID" or "carid", because they're just wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protobuff descriptor (.proto) are case insensitive. If you try to compile:

```
message Car{
    string carId = 1;
    string carid =2;
}
```

You will have the compilation error:

```
CARID_FIELD_NUMBER is already defined in ...
```

Also you have to know that for proto3, the JSON parser are dealing with lowerCamelCase. As stated on reference guide:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json

> Use proto field name instead of lowerCamelCase name: By default proto3
>   JSON printer should convert the field name to lowerCamelCase and use
>   that as the JSON name. An implementation may provide an option to use
>   proto field name as the JSON name instead. Proto3 JSON parsers are
>   required to accept both the converted lowerCamelCase name and the
>   proto field name.

From your parser point of view "carID" and "CarID" are the same, because it will automatically convert "CarID" to "carID". But "carId" and "carid" will always be different.